# merge Database records when keys match and add values

Tags: php, mysql, merge

I wish to select all records from a database and then combine matching keys and also adding their values.

```
Col1     col2 
-----  ------
ABC       2
ABA       3
ADD       1
AED       3
ABC       2
ABA       3
ADD       1
AED       3
```

So i would end up with

```
array("
    ABC  =>       4,
    ABA  =>       6,
    ADD  =>       2,
    AED  =>       6");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basic [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) application:

```
SELECT Col1, SUM(col2) FROM tbl GROUP BY Col1
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d1f8/1 for an example

Comment: thanks, would this return the keys already merged and calculated?

Comment: This would produce a result pretty much exactly as you expect.

Comment: @TheApptracker I've update my answer to provide a sqlfiddle as a live example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I'm stil feeling my way around anything that is more involved than 'select', 'insert' and 'delete'.